# How to edit a data where data is exist on database? on codeigniter 3

Tags: database, codeigniter

so I want to edit a data for example,  I want to change `category_name`, `product_name`, and quantity but I want check first is exist on database or not

the problem is I already make a validation for `category_name` and `product_name` is cannot be the same, but when change the quantity its didn't change because `category_name` and `productname` is already exist

```
$('form#formedit').on('submit', async function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    const category_name= $('input[name="category"]').val();
    const product_name= $('select[name="product"]').val();

    const result = await cekProduct(category_name, product_name);
    
    
    // if data is exist
    if (result > 0) {
        alert(`category_name: ${category_name} , product_name:${product_name} already exist`);
        
    }else{
     //run edit function
```

how to edit data itself with checking a same data on database? thanks for the attention

I'm using ajax with model and controller codeigniter

Comment: see [MySQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)

Comment: how to set it on codeigniter? do you have an example for it? @Vickel

Comment: please read the database section of the CI docs: starting with [Database usage examples](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/examples.html) and then [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)